# Add constraint to UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I want to add a smaller subview in a view and add constraint to it. The leading and trainling constraint should be 50.0 and the height and botton should be 80.0 .

I create my subview in this way

```
let mySubview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 80.0, width: 540.0, height: 220.0))
```

and then I try to add it to the view with this code

```
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 80.0)
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 80.0)
let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 50.0)
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 50.0)

mySubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(mySubview)
self.view.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

But the contraints dose not do any effect. The view looks nice on iPad, probably because of the first init `CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 80.0, width: 540.0, height: 220.0)`, but on smaller screen it looks very big. Shall I try to init the UIView depending on the screen or is it possible to solve this by adding constrains?

Answer (score 3):

You need this:

```
mySubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

> **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints** is a Boolean value that
>   determines whether the view’s autoresizing mask is translated into
>   Auto Layout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use auto layout it is enough to instantiate the subview without a frame (since the frame gets calculated taking the constraints into account): `let mySubview = UIView()`.

Then you have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for your subview.

You also have to change the constants for the bottom constraint to **-80** and for the trailing constraint to **-50**. if you want to keep the positive constants you can also switch the items (`self.view` / `mySubview`):

```
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mySubview, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 80.0)
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mySubview, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 50.0)
```

Last but not least you can delete the `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` line.

Answer (score 1):

you should try to use http://snapkit.io/docs/

```
let box = UIView()
superview.addSubview(box)

box.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.top.equalTo(superview).offset(80)
    make.left.equalTo(superview).offset(50)
    make.bottom.equalTo(superview).offset(-80)
    make.right.equalTo(superview).offset(-50)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`

```
let mySubview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 80.0, width: 540.0, height: 220.0))

mySubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can solve the problem

```
mySubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Like this

```
let mySubview: UIView = {
    let thisView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 80.0, width: 540.0, height: 220.0))
    thisView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return thisView
}()
```